# Merge Data Frames in python with different column names and datatypes - 241 columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames.

The first one has header with one row of data providing description of the header columns (241 Columns).

RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Columns: 241 entries, FILEID to B0_235
dtypes: float64(6), object(235)
memory usage: 2.0+ KB

The second data frame has no header record, with 241 columns. Here are the details

RangeIndex: 11718 entries, 0 to 11717
Columns: 241 entries, 0 to 240
dtypes: float64(187), int64(52), object(2)
memory usage: 21.5+ MB

I append/merge dataframe 1 with dataframe 2 with 11719 records and header from dataframe 1

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. By minimal, we mean you can use, say, 5 column instead of 241. Provide some data and show us your existing code. This way we can correctly identify your problem.

Comment: I found workaround by just changing the header
df.columns=dfs2.columns